# How to display previous page after validation (logging in)?

Tags: login, magento2.2, redirect-url

In my store I create PDF file for each order, that can only be accessed by customer. To validate if user can access order I first check if order was created by:

- guest (then `\Magento\Sales\Helper\Guest $guestAuthorization`and`$guestAuthorization->loadValidOrder($request)`. False returns resultRedirect Object)
- registered user (then `\Magento\Sales\Controller\AbstractController\OrderViewAuthorization $loggedAuthorization`and`$loggedAuthorization->canView($order)`. False returns FALSE and I create resultRedirect Object `$resultRedirect = $this->_resultRedirectFactory->create();$resultRedirect->setUrl('/customer/account/login');`

The problem is once user verifies either by logging in or guest order form I want to redirect him to previous URL (the PDF file). What is the easiest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try before you redirect the customer to login the following

```
$this->customerSession->setBeforeAuthUrl('url_to_your_pdf');
```

where the customerSession is an instance of

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
```

Comment: This doesn't work (has no effect). I set it before resultRedirect in controller responsible for displaying pdf. Do I have to override Login and Guest Form controllers and put above code in them?

Comment: My apologies. Above code is working as expected for registered users. Thank you very much! Turns out I've passed url that doesn't exist and Magento performed another redirect.
Unfortunately it is not working for guest verification. Is there a similar method?

Comment: There seems to be no similar method for guest verification. I have decided to create a button to pdf on guest order page to allow access without using redirect. Accepting answer, because it has solved part for registered users. Thank you!